# UILabel lines are overlapping when using custom font

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is my first time installing a custom font into an XCode project, and I am noticing that when I try to use it there is no line separation.

[image]

When I go back to the 'System' font, the issue is corrected.

The lines parameter is set to 2, and the font was set up in info.plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Avenir LT 35 Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Avenir LT 55 Roman.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

and on my appDelegate as the default font:

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Avenir LT 55 Roman", size: 14)
```

Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: The version of the font may have issues with its line height.  What happens if you swap to another font?

Comment: I suspect you have a bad font. I grabbed one off the web, and it has `.lineHeight`, `.ascender` and `.descender` all at Zero. You can "fix" it by using paragraph styles on attributed strings, but a better option would be to get a better version of the font.